# PJSIP Get Codec from current call

Tags: c++, pjsip

I want to log which codec is used on a specific call.
I'm using PJSIP to make the call, but I don't know to get the codec from an active call.
Can someone point me to how I can get the currently used codec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `pjmedia_stream_get_info` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__STRM.htm#ga54c3836e9b18c497990f355e4c950558)) function, which takes pointer to structure `pjmedia_stream_info` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/structpjmedia__stream__info.htm)) as its second argument. Then you can get negotiated codec name from `pjmedia_codec_info` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/structpjmedia__codec__info.htm)) structure, which is a part of stream information.